# Realtek drivers on a Lenovo X200 running Ubuntu 9.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wireless-networking

I just bought a Lenovo X200 and it has a Realtek wireless card. I have installed Ubuntu 9.04 on it.

There are a number of suggestions online about how to get the wireless drivers for the Realtek card but none of them seem to work and the authors themselves claim their suggestions may not work.

Any ideas on how to get wireless working with a Realtek card?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this will answer your question but since you did not mention if you tried NDISWrapper for this I'll include the information on it here. If you do not know NDISWrapper allows you to load Windows network card drivers in Linux.

To install it in Ubuntu 9.04 just do the following:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ndisgtk ndiswrapper-common ndiswrapper-utils-1.9
```

The full detail on how to set it up can be found on the [Ubuntu community documentation under WifiDocsDriverNdiswrapper](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/Ndiswrapper) and some more information can be found on the [NDSWrapper wiki](http://ndiswrapper.sourceforge.net)

Comment: Tried ndiswrapper over the weekend. Module loads but the wireless icon is still dark. No wlan devices found.

Answer (score 0):

Before using the ndiswrapper route I would recommend just trying to install the backports:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-backports-modules-jaunty
```

This helps my Realtek without any other prying/hacking.

Comment: Did the backports install and a reboot. The wireless card is still not discovered :(

Comment: then I would highly recommend going the ndiswrapper route. sorry it didn't help.

Comment: I also tried the rtl8170 module. The kernel module built successfully AND loaded without problems when I did modprobe, but the wireless icon is still dark!